# Having trouble with testing if a thing in a list exists in python

Tags: python, list, pygame

Ok, so I am creating a game with pygame with clones and to do that I made a list to include all the classes, but sometimes it releases an error that the item in the list does not exist/out of range.

i am using a "for i in range(list.**len**()):"
and I need to test if "i" exists or is out of range, it is not a number list so I can't simply just do
if "i" in list: i tried something like this to - "if list[i]:" but that does not work and also "if i>list.**len**()"; (p.s. i left out all of the classes and extra stuff)

```py
import pygame
listone = [] #length
clo = clone(100, 100, pygame.Surface((50, 50)), (255, 0, 0)) #sprite class i added
clo.clone() #basically clones and appends the sprite/class clo to listone
while running:
  def function():
   for i in range(list.__len__()):
    if #see if i exists in listone:
     listone[i].display #displays the sprite clones
     #There is a lot of classes and code i left out, i'm just showing the place where i need help and a little more
```

It will sometimes say "IndexError: list index out of range"
and I need that to stop so my window won't close and for the game to actually work so I need to check if "i" exists...

Comment: `i` should never be outside the bounds of the list, you should figure out why that error is occurring instead. (Also why aren't you just iterating the elements of the list with the more natural `for element in list:`?)

Comment: should also never call a list named list

Comment: `l = clo.clone()` ? *list* clashes with Python's built in function and you can't use it to name lists.

Comment: oh.. these variables aren't the real variables I use in my code, my mistake for making a variable named list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the index exists by doing a simple comparison:

```
if i < len(listone):
   listone[i].display
```

This leads me to ask - are you doing something that modifies the size of the list as you are looping through it? I think that would be useful for you to show us.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there was a len() function this really helped!